# Print man contents as help prompt of a C program

Tags: c

I plan to use [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/) to generate the `man` files from markdown for a very small C program.

I do not want to repeat myself and type the **help prompt** (`command [ -h | --help ]`) into the source code of the program.

#### Question

**Q:** Could I permanently **include** man content from a file at compile time of a C program?
OR
**Q:** Is there a way in **C** to print the contents of the installed man page to stdout?

---

#### [WIP] Solution

Based on [@KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66992164/13982210) here's what i am doing:

In terminal:

```sh
file command.1
# OUTPUT --> command.1: troff or preprocessor input, ASCII text

xxd -i command.1 > command.hex
```

Then in *main.c*

```
#include "command.hex"
printf("%s", command_1);
```

This is **almost** exactly what I am looking for except

1. I need the hexed troff to be parsed before printing. Or parsed before hexing. I am not sure which to do / how to do that.

   - No, I do not want to call `man` and pipe the output.
2. I would prefer using a library + a macro to generate the hex but I am not sure how it's done.

---

#### Clarifications

What I mean by **help prompt**:

- The output of `git --help` which prints to *stdout*
- **NOT** the output of `git --help branch` which opens the man for git-branch

However, please do share the latter too. It isn't what I want: my manual is very short; but I would be glad to learn an alternative if not the exact one I seek.

---

#### Considerations I have noted:

1. man pages are not always installed to the same location
2. man pages may not be installed in some systems; or there may be no `man` program

Comment: `Is there a way in C to print the contents of the installed man page?` Well, `system("man man")`. Wait, you mean __print__ the content as a stream, or display the content in a pager?

Comment: @KamilCuk stream. stdin. similar to the output of ```file --help``` for example. i would appreciate if you could tell me how to open with the pager too, though that isn't the exact solution i am looking for. my manual is going to be very very short.

Comment: i mean stdout* idk why i said stdin. sorry

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch could you please add an example or elaborate? i am very much new to C; frankly i have no idea what you mean by generating C code. please note that i am trying to simple display text in the terminal. a help/usage prompt - that's all

Comment: [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) is generating C code. It is a [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (coded mostly in C, documented in English), and you are allowed to download it, study its source code, and improve it. And you could use [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your computer and read http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: Is your C program open source? If yes, where is the source code??? (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch merci pour votre aide. mais je veux pas vous causer encore plus d'ennui et de la perte de temps avec mon app simple (et bête) qui ne sert que moi. comme vous avez suggéré, je vais dédier le temps pour la recherche. encore, merci. bonne journée.

Answer (score 2):

> Could I permanently include man content from a file at compile time?

You can include any content of any file at compile time. The simplest is use `xxd -i` and compile the output.

> Is there a way in C to print the contents of the installed man page?

You can troff output from `man -k`

You can get output from `man` by replacing pager, along `MANPAGER=cat man`.

In C:  `setenv("MANPAGER", "cat"); execp("man", (char*[]){"man", "something", 0});` or just `system("MANPAGER=cat man some_command")`.

> man pages are not always installed to the same location

And system administractors can use `/etc/man_db.conf` to configure the behavior of `man` command.

> man pages may not be installed in some systems; or there may be no man program

So it seems users of such systems do not care about man pages, so there's no point in supporting such cases.

I believe your intention is to render a man page from your program, where you have a static troff input saved and want to use `man` to display it. You could save the input to a file, save it and pass the filename to `man` - man will parse troff and render it. Or you could the usual `pipe()+fork()+exec()` and from one process pass troff data to stdin to `man -` - the `-` will make `man` read troff input from stdin.

Comment: i'm updating my question with queries. need larger code fences. thank you for your suggestions. the first part is relevant and seems perfect for my use. i prefer not to fork because i usually code in bash; are there library alternatives? is forking common and good practice in C? i am new to C.

Comment: `I prefer not to fork because i usually code in bash` that sounds like oxymoron, bash calls `fork()` on (very small almost) every single command. `are there library alternatives?` No idea. Use python. Or bash. `is forking common` yes. Every time you run __any__ program there's a `fork()+exec()` call. `good practice in C?` `fork()` is just a tool you use to get another process. In that sense.. it's good practice, because it's the tool to do it.

Comment: haha. we use bash's built-ins as much as we can. maybe i am wrong about how it works under the hood :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in C to print the contents of the installed man page to stdout?

You could invoke the `man`command by using a pipe stream . Function `popen` is what you are looking for. More info [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

This is an `fgets()` solution, though you might want to be careful, in case you want to read more characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char buffer[1000];

    fp  = popen("man man","r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
       /* error running the command */
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp))
    {
        puts(buffer);
    }

    fclose(fp);    

    return 0;
}
```

`getline()` solution, in case you don't know how many bytes you are going to read.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t len = 0U;
    ssize_t nread = 0;

    fp  = popen("man man","r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
       /* error running the command */
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* getline will set errno uppon failure, you might want to check that too */

    while ((nread = getline(&buffer,&len,fp)) != -1)
    {
       buffer[nread] = 0; /* NULL terminate your buffer */
       puts(buffer);
    }
    
    free(buffer);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

More on `getline()` [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: hadn't considered *executing* `man` to get the content---mostly because that would be forking and in bash (my usual language) that's not preferred. i like your answer nonetheless; i did not know about either of these solutions. thank you :)

Comment: @kevinnls: Why do you believe that `fork`ing is not prefered in bash? It does that on every command (except builtins like `cd`)?

Comment: built-ins are used as much as possible. or at least, that is how i have learnt bash. e.g parameter expansion instead of sed

Comment: Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your typical `bash` process

Answer (score 1):

The `man`  program is written in C and is open source. It is more complex than you believe, since it deals with terminal (and their width). See also [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and [tty(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html). Be aware of [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library. Take into account that in 2021 [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/), and that some `man` pages could contain `§` or `°` characters. Be also aware of [internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) issues, see [locale(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html). In France, a lot of Linux systems are installed with `man` pages in French.

So you could get the [source code of the `man-db` package](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/man-db), study it, and incorporate it inside your program.

My opinion is that it would be silly to do so.

You could instead read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), study various [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), and use [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to run the *existing* and *installed* `/usr/bin/man` program (whose existence could be tested with [test(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) or [access(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) or [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) in C code; but if it does not exist your  [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) will fail...)

Regarding display of `--help`, you could use (if so allowed) GNU libc [program argument parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) facilities, and take inspiration from the source code of existing free software programs, such as [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

Of course, your build infrastructure (e.g. your `Makefile` if you build your software with [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) could run programs to *share* data and textual descriptions. You could (if so allowed) use open source tools to *generate* some C code (e.g. `#include`d stuff) at build time, such as [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), etc..

Take also inspiration from the source code of [git](https://git-scm.com/). It is open source (and useful for you): you can download its source code and study it.

Comment: hmm thanks. i'll take a look at it. GNU coreutils was my reference. i didn't want to use print statements and hard code the text. as that would require my changing/updating in two places: man.md and the code each time

Comment: i had not however considered the implications of terminal width etc. thank you for pointing it out

Comment: No,, you would update one file, and have utilities generating C code and `man` pages from it. This is usual practice.

Comment: if possible, please guide me to an example (or provide one) to using utilities. i am not familiar with preprocessing nor with macros. also, does using utilities circumvent the locale problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have no time for that. Budget an entire week of reading efforts. Or subcontract your work to companies able to do that. An I have no ideas about `man` pages written in Japanese, but they do exist